# Failed deliver with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have this method in my reports controller :

```
def send_status
 date = Date.today
 reports = current_user.reports.for_date(date)
 ReportMailer.status_email(current_user, reports, date).deliver
 reports.update_all(:sent_mail => true)
 head :ok
 rescue => e
 render text: e.message, status: :bad_request
end
```

I cannot make any request when sending this status so I use delayed_job, replacing

ReportMailer.status_email(current_user, reports, date).deliver with
ReportMailer.status_email(current_user, reports, date).send_later(:send_status)

but I get 400 bad request on delivery.Any help? Thanks!

Comment: It would help if the exact error stacktrace is known. Instead of a catch-all rescue statement, use specific error classes to avoid ambiguity while debugging. What is the error that you get if you remove the rescue block?

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms

TypeError (can't dump anonymous module: #<Module:0xc9c9cc4>):
  app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:97:in `send_status'

Comment: I also tried ReportMailer.delay.status_email(current_user, reports, date)

Answer (score 2):

Avoid passing objects to delayed_job and use ids instead: (your delayed_job process might be failing silently)

```
ReportMailer.delay.status_email(current_user.id, reports_ids, date)
```

And inside status_email, pull the current_user and reports:

```
def status_email(userid, reports_ids, date)
  current_user = User.find_by_id(userid)
  reports = Report.find_all_by_id(reports_ids)
  ...
end
```